# Centering text inside the label view of the android actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

This is the label of my activity in the actionbar with "Show layout bounds" option enabled. 
As you can see the label area is centered, but the text inside it is moved to bottom. So it appears like the text is not centered.
How to center the text vertically?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should provide some additional information like the definition of the layout.xml file.